# Using 4G LTE modem with dialup connection

Tags: networking, internet, modem, dial-up, cellular-internet

I just reformatted my PC and getting frustrated with my 3G/4G modem. When I plug the modem it asks me to install the software, which I did already. Then I am opening the Modem software and trying to connect. Then I get this exception:

[image]

If I go to network settings there is another adapter already installed (Cellular connection). If I click connect to that it connects and internet works fine. 
Now my problem is when I connect the LAN cable to my PC it starts using the internet from LAN instead of modem. Before when I used the 3G/4G modem iy used to connect as a DialUp connection and even when I plug the LAN cable PC used the internet from modem.

How can I disable the Cellular connection and use the dialup instead?